# Product cart slide in or pop-up instead of redirect

Tags: e-commerce, checkout, shopping-cart

I'm in process of redesigning a website for my company, in cooperation with a digital agency. Our business is one of the leading companies in our country that sells consumer electronics (notebooks, PCs, smartphones, tablets, cameras etc.).

I have idea to place product cart in fixed position box which displays on any page, any time when user click on the cart icon. For me it is more useful and clear - you can fast check out your cart, edit it etc. Ofcourse after click go to the checkout there will be redirection to new page with checkout process.

Is that any hard data after or against sliding in or pop-up card instead of redirection?

Comment: Would the cart be persistent while the user is browsing other items? Ie would the fixed box persist after a page reload or if the user follow a link to some other product on the page?

Comment: Sure, this is the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found [that](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/shopping-cart/).

According to this article there should be always full screen cart even if you use "quick cart".

Answer (score 3):

Many e-commerce sites provide redirection including popular sites like [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com), [Flipkart](http://www.flipkart.com)

But I think instead of redirection the idea of *pop-up* or *slide-in* is really cool!!

You can see the pop-up implementation in [SnapDeal](http://www.snapdeal.com/) and I don't think there's anything against this approach.

**Checkout the snapshot:**

[image]

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any studies on 'quick' carts that I can find, however, it is well documented that speed is essential for website users. Load times are a good example here. A lot of users will abandon sites if they take too long to load. (https://blog.kissmetrics.com/loading-time/)

With this in mind, one could assume that a quick, load in-place cart that allows basic actions to be performed without leaving the page (removing an accidentally added item, increasing amount of a certain item, checking price etc...) would keep more user engaged and convert more.

Slightly off-topic, this article has a lot of tips on cart optimisations: http://unbounce.com/conversion-rate-optimization/shopping-cart-abandonment-infographic/